# Excepción cuando no se puede eliminar un registro existente en dos tablas

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

al momento de querer eliminar un registro de mi tabla Categorias en C# con SQL Server me sale que no se puede porque ese registro existe en otra tabla (como aparece en la imagen) y quiero saber si es posible crear una Excepción para que en vez de ese mensaje de advertencia me mande un mensaje que diga lo que yo quiero. Gracias.[image: Advertencia al presionar el boton de eliminar en c#]

Comment: donde aparece ese mensaje?

Answer (score 2):

Si entiendo bien sólo necesitas aplicar un bloque `try {...} catch (Exception ) {...}`.

Simplemente mete tu código donde trates de eliminar el registro en un bloque con el siguiente formato:

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    // ...

    try
    {
        // Tu código para borrar datos SQL.
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // Mostrar tu mensaje personalizado al usuario.
    }
    finally
    {
        // Si necesitas hacer algo después, haya excepción o no, como cerrar la conexión.
    }
```